# How2 keyframe & trigger (retrieve+play) an action incl variable transform values (custom attributes) as with an Action Constraint (no timeline)?

Tags: python, animation, geometry-nodes, custom-properties, timer

My goal is similar to interactively actuating a controller to drive action constraints, but where some keyframes include variables (pref. custom attributes) for transform & shape key (and shader node) values. FIRST n objects are set at variable START locations along a curve (radius=yLoc, Obj(n),xLoc1 = variable-start for each object). SECOND, A common DESTINATION location (xLoc2 =end) is set for all objects). THIRD, a control (c1) is actuated that selects a corresponding (numbered) object and a control (c2) initiates (plays) an action for that object that translates that object from its xLoc1 (variable start) to its xLoc2 (common end).

Ideally, multiple ones of the objects can be similarly highlighted when selected and then collected to the destination. Also ideally, the timeline, dope sheet, non-lin... are not used for interactive collecting.

Problems: Apparently, action constraints do not consider any custom attributes in an action. They also don't provide the current frame and playback is invariably affected by the speed of controller (target) actuation.

Frame-based drivers/geoNodes also seem to require setting the timeline to continually cycle (and I haven't found "solo-play" or "group-mutePlay" features, e.g., as with midi-sequencing solutions).

I did find a Python example invoking a timer to play an action but not further support... and I'd prefer to use (or at least set/pass/update) custom object attributes, as these are accessible in the n-panel by default.

I've also tried animating with Delta Transforms and curve tracking works, but resulting action transforms (while local & with all objects having a origin at world origin) have been inconsistent and hard to debug at best

I hope my description is clear enough, but would very much appreciate any help.